# Can I apply the Great Weapon Master feat's second benefit (-5 to attack roll, +10 to damage roll) to the bonus-action attack from the first benefit?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, attack, actions

Say I trigger the bonus-action attack granted by the first benefit of the Great Weapon Master feat (PHB, p. 167), either by getting a crit or a killing blow. Can I then apply GWM's second benefit (-5 to attack roll, +10 to damage roll) to that bonus-action attack?

As a barbarian at level 5 (Extra Attack) , this would mean that I could use this feature a total of 3 times in a turn — that's some heavy damage.

Comment: Related: [Does the extra attack from Great Weapon Master apply to all melee weapons?](/questions/130397), [How does the Great Weapon Master feat bonus damage combine with Extra Attack?](/questions/138855)

Comment: Do note that it is some heavy damage _only_ if you hit.

Answer (score 20):

### Yes, you can take -5 to hit/+10 damage on the bonus-action attack.

The [Great Weapon Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/great-weapon-master) feat (PHB, p. 167) reads:

> [...] you can **make one melee weapon attack** as a bonus action.

and

> Before you **make a melee attack** with a heavy weapon that you are proficient with, [...]

So whenever you make a melee attack (with a heavy weapon that you are proficient in), including one provided by the feat, you can take the - 5 to hit for the +10 damage. This can be done any number of times - so yes, your barbarian could do it on three attacks (attack, extra attack, bonus-action attack) in a turn.